# Prevent `cat` from leaving characters after carriage return ("\r")

Tags: r

### Problem

I'm working on a progress bar that mimics the timer from the {pbapply} package:

`|++++                           | 10% ~calculating`

After the progress bar figures out how much time is remaining, the progress bar turns over:

`|+++++                          | 12% ~22s`

So far, I have been able to mimic this latter feature. However, when trying to add the `~calculating` text, I achieve this result:

`|+++++                          | 12% ~22sulating`

I would like to make `calculating` disappear and not leave text over so that only `~22s` is displayed.

### Toy example

A toy example of this behavior is demonstrated here:

```
# Toy example
for(i in 1:100){
  
  # Sleep for a quarter second
  Sys.sleep(0.25)
  
  # Update progress
  if(i < 10){
    
    cat(
      sprintf(
        paste0("\r |%-49s| %s"), # Timer setup
        paste(rep("+", i / 2), collapse = ""), # Internal fill
        paste0(i, "% ~calculating") # Percent complete and time remaining
      )
    )
    
  }else{
    
    # Timing
    timing <- round((100 - i) * 0.25)
    
    cat(
      sprintf(
        paste0("\r |%-49s| %s"), # Timer setup
        paste(rep("+", i / 2), collapse = ""), # Internal fill
        paste0(i, "% ~", timing, "s") # Percent complete and time remaining
      )
    )
  }
  
}
```

### Question

How can I avoid `~22sulating` and instead have `22s` while keeping the preliminary `~calculating`?

### Things I've tried:

`\f` = flushes entire console

`flush.console()` = does nothing as far as I can tell

Comment: A little hacky, but maybe `paste0(i, "% ~", timing, "s       ")`

Comment: Hacky works for me -- thanks! Feel free to drop as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need enough whitespace characters asfter the "s" to cover up the string `"ulating"`.

```
paste0(i, "% ~", timing, "s       ")
```